# Percentage on rows/columns in pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I've dataframe `df`:

```
df.head()
                     M1       M2      M3       M4
Timestamp                                                       
2018-09-20 12:59:57  cat 1    obj_1   name_1   1
2018-09-20 12:58:53  cat 1    obj_2   name_2   1
2018-09-20 12:57:44  else 1   obj_3   name_1   1
2018-09-20 12:57:19  cat 11   obj_2   name_1   1
2018-09-20 12:56:17  cat 11   obj_2   name_1   1
```

With this `df` I'm preparing a set of pivot tables for each column presenting both percentage (%) of occurrences as well as it's count  (N):

```
df[['M1']].pivot_table(index=df.index.date, aggfunc=(
    ('%', lambda x: len(x) / df['M1'].count()), 
    ('N', 'size')))
```

When I come across to preparing pivot table on two series I'd like to display the percentage of occurrences of `M1` not in the whole dataframe but in relation to M2 categories. 
So far I've tried to set the denominator to `M2` count, but it's the overall count and not the count of `M1` within specific `M2` categories:

```
df[['M1', 'M2']].pivot_table(columns='M2', index='M1', aggfunc=(lambda x: len(x) / df['M2'].count()))
```

Any clues how to get specific percentage of `M1` in each `M2` category?
Expected output:

```
M2       obj_1    obj_2    obj_3
M1
cat 1    value1   value*   value*
cat 2    value*   value*   value*
...      ...      ...      ...
cat 11   value*   value*   value*
else 1   value*   value*   value*
```

where `value1` is number of occurrences of `cat 1` within all occurrences of `obj_1` etc.

Comment: please provide the expected output as a table. that is much easier to understand than the text explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupby` to find number of `M2`'s for each category, and add it as a column to your dataframe as follows

```
df['count_M2'] = df.groupby('M2')['M1'].transform('count')
```

Then you run the `pivot_table` function to get the percentage of `M1`'s in each `M2` group

```
df.pivot_table(values=['count_M2'], index=['M1'], columns=['M2'], 
               aggfunc=lambda x: len(x) / x.iloc[0])
```

---

**Details**

df

```
                  Time      M1     M2      M3  M4  count_M2
0  2018-09-20 12:59:57   cat 1  obj_1  name_1   1         1
1  2018-09-20 12:58:53   cat 1  obj_2  name_2   1         3
2  2018-09-20 12:57:44  else 1  obj_3  name_1   1         1
3  2018-09-20 12:57:19  cat 11  obj_2  name_1   1         3
4  2018-09-20 12:56:17  cat 11  obj_2  name_1   1         3
```

df.pivot_table

```
       count_M2                
M2        obj_1     obj_2 obj_3
M1                             
cat 1       1.0  0.333333   NaN
cat 11      NaN  0.666667   NaN
else 1      NaN       NaN   1.0
```